# SQL Server : how can I get difference between counts of total rows and those with only data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with data as shown below (the table is built every day with current date, but I left off that field for ease of reading).

This table keeps track of people and the doors they enter on a daily basis.

Table **entrance_t**:

```
id   entrance   entered
------------------------
1    a          0
1    b          0
1    c          0
1    d          0

2    a          1
2    b          0
2    c          0
2    d          0

3    a          0
3    b          1
3    c          1
3    d          1
```

My goal is to report on people and count entrances not used(grouping on people), but ONLY if they entered(entered=1).

So using the above table, I would like the results of query to be...

```
id   count
----------
2    3
3    1
```

(id=2 did not use 3 of the entrances and id=3 did not use 1)

I tried queries(some with inner joins on two instances of same table) and I can get the entrances not used, but it's always for everybody. Like this...

```
id   count
----------
1    4
2    3
3    1
```

How do I not display results id=1 since they did not enter at all?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id, count(CASE WHEN entered = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt
FROM entrance_t
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(CASE WHEN entered = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3d0e5034a95b7996366eb96ae8cc591e)**